# Tool for testing usability design of a system architecture

Tags: testing, architecture

I have this payroll system architecture that uses three tier architecture. Our instructor requires as to look for a tool that can test the usability of the design of the system architecture of the payroll system. I am having problem looking for this tool. Can anyone suggests what tools can be used for measuring usability of the payroll system architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Go to webusability.com, then click on usability tools, and then click on card sorting and navigation. Click on either Treejack or Tree Testing.  Both of these tools will allow you to measure the goodness of the system architecture from the user's point of view.

Comment: wow your response is too late. Why only now. sorry but I already tool but it takes me some time to find such tool.